# Dynamicly rebinding an extender doesnt update the view

Tags: knockout.js

I have an extender that checks the min/max length of a target. I need to set the min/max dynamically based on a dropdown select. If the min/max is out of range, the observable has an `hasError`, that will update my view with a css class. The issue is once I rebind the extender, the view doesnt update. Here is my extender:

```
ko.extenders.minmaxlength = function (target, options) {

    target.min = ko.observable(options.min);
    target.max = ko.observable(options.max);
    target.hasError = ko.observable(false);

    function validate(newValue) {      

        if (newValue.length > options.max || newValue.length < options.min){
            target.hasError(true);            
        } else {
            target.hasError(false);       
        }    
    }
    validate(target());
    target.subscribe(validate);    
};
```

Here is where I rebind the bind and rebind extender:

```
self.newValue = ko.observable('').extend({ minmaxlength: { min: 3, max: 30 } }); // defaults

self.selectedType.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == undefined) {
        return;
    }
    var obj = self.pricingTypes().filter(function (i) {
        return i.Id == newValue;
    });

    if (obj.length > 0) {
        var objType = obj[0];
        self.selectedTypeObj(ko.mapping.fromJS(objType));  
        // rebind the extender here
        self.newValue = ko.observable('').extend({ minmaxlength: { min: self.selectedTypeObj().MinLength(), max: self.selectedTypeObj().MaxLength() } });
        self.newValue.valueHasMutated()
    } else {
        return; // bad value
    }

});
```

When I debug, I see the extender being called and setting the `hasError` function correctly, but again, the view doesnt update.

Here is the input:

```
    <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: $root.newValue, css: { 'requiredField': $root.newValue.hasError() } "/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change the values of a KO extender at run time. But I've never done that before, so I tried passing observables into the extender, and then changing those observable values in the `.subscribe()` callback, but no luck.

I recommend using computed instead. It looks like you have access to all the values you would need in your view model.

```js
function TestViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.minLength = ko.observable(3); // default min
  self.maxLength = ko.observable(30); // default max
  self.newValue = ko.observable(null);
  self.newValueIsValid = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (!self.newValue()) {
      return;
    }
    if (self.newValue().length > self.maxLength() || self.newValue().length < self.minLength()) {
      console.log("invalid");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("valid");
      return true;
    }
  });
  self.selectedType = ko.observable("default value");
  self.selectedType.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    self.minLength(5); // new min
    self.maxLength(50); // new max
  });
}

var vm = new TestViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.newValue("test");
vm.newValueIsValid(); // should be valid with default min/max
vm.newValue("something really too long to be valid");
vm.newValueIsValid(); // should be invalid with default min/max

vm.selectedType("changed value");

vm.newValue("test");
vm.newValueIsValid(); // should be invalid with new min/max
vm.newValue("something really too long to be valid");
vm.newValueIsValid(); // should be valid with new min/max
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```